# A disc's recursive path : Time to long C++

Tags: winapi

I want to build a class similar to "CFindDialog" with MFC Windows with color. I route the disk with a recursive function that uses "FindFirstFile". But when I switch to settings the system disk (C: . . .). The time is to long several seconds and so I'm on an SDD.
I have two questions:

- Are there any low-level functions that allow you to go faster?
- How does DLL comdlg32 go so fast?

Jean Bezet

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find the "CFindDialog" class you mentioned, but you could try [Windows Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/windows-search), First is to index the drive you want to search(Only once):

Control Panel> Index Option> Modify, check the dirves.

There are some code samples in the document, and I also provide a sample without UI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61380966/10611792). I made some simple modifications to this sample to specify the search content:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <searchapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <atldbcli.h>

using namespace std;

class CMyAccessor
{
public:
    WCHAR _szItemUrl[2048];
    __int64 _size;
    BEGIN_COLUMN_MAP(CMyAccessor)
        COLUMN_ENTRY(1, _szItemUrl)
        COLUMN_ENTRY(2, _size)
    END_COLUMN_MAP()
};
HRESULT GetSQLStringFromParams(LCID lcidContentLocaleParam,
    PCWSTR pszContentPropertiesParam,
    LCID lcidKeywordLocaleParam,
    LONG nMaxResultsParam,
    PCWSTR pszSelectColumnsParam,
    PCWSTR pszSortingParam,
    SEARCH_QUERY_SYNTAX sqsSyntaxParam,
    SEARCH_TERM_EXPANSION steTermExpansionParam,
    PCWSTR pszWhereRestrictionsParam,
    PCWSTR pszExprParam,
    PWSTR* ppszSQL)
{
    ISearchQueryHelper* pQueryHelper;

    // Create an instance of the search manager
    ISearchManager* pSearchManager;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CSearchManager), NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSearchManager));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Get the catalog manager from the search manager
        ISearchCatalogManager* pSearchCatalogManager;
        hr = pSearchManager->GetCatalog(L"SystemIndex", &pSearchCatalogManager);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Get the query helper from the catalog manager
            hr = pSearchCatalogManager->GetQueryHelper(&pQueryHelper);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = pQueryHelper->put_QueryContentLocale(lcidContentLocaleParam);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = pQueryHelper->put_QueryContentProperties(pszContentPropertiesParam);
                }
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = pQueryHelper->put_QueryKeywordLocale(lcidKeywordLocaleParam);
                }
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = pQueryHelper->put_QueryMaxResults(nMaxResultsParam);
                }
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = pQueryHelper->put_QuerySelectColumns(pszSelectColumnsParam);
                }
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = pQueryHelper->put_QuerySorting(pszSortingParam);
                }
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = pQueryHelper->put_QuerySyntax(sqsSyntaxParam);
                }
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = pQueryHelper->put_QueryTermExpansion(steTermExpansionParam);
                }
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = pQueryHelper->put_QueryWhereRestrictions(pszWhereRestrictionsParam);
                }
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = pQueryHelper->GenerateSQLFromUserQuery(pszExprParam, ppszSQL);
                }
                pQueryHelper->Release();
            }
            pSearchCatalogManager->Release();
        }
        pSearchManager->Release();
    }
    return hr;
}


void WindowsSearch(PCWSTR szPath, PCWSTR szFileName)
{
    PWSTR pszSQL;
    wstring script = L"AND SCOPE ='file:///";
    script += szPath;
    script += L"'";
    wstring filename = L"FileName:";
    filename += szFileName;
    HRESULT hr = GetSQLStringFromParams(1033, L"", 1033, -1, L"System.ItemPathDisplay, System.Size",
        L"", SEARCH_ADVANCED_QUERY_SYNTAX, SEARCH_TERM_NO_EXPANSION, script.c_str(),
        filename.c_str(), &pszSQL);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        wcout << L"Generated query: " << pszSQL << endl;

        CDataSource cDataSource;
        hr = cDataSource.OpenFromInitializationString(L"provider=Search.CollatorDSO.1;EXTENDED PROPERTIES='Application=Windows'");
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            CSession cSession;
            hr = cSession.Open(cDataSource);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                // cCommand is derived from CMyAccessor which has binding information in column map
                // This allows ATL to put data directly into apropriate class members.
                CCommand<CAccessor<CMyAccessor>, CRowset> cCommand;
                hr = cCommand.Open(cSession, pszSQL);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    __int64 maxValue = 0;
                    __int64 minValue = ULONG_MAX;

                    for (hr = cCommand.MoveFirst(); S_OK == hr; hr = cCommand.MoveNext())
                    {
                        wcout << cCommand._szItemUrl << L": " << cCommand._size << L" bytes" << endl;

                        maxValue = max(maxValue, cCommand._size);
                        minValue = min(minValue, cCommand._size);
                    }

                    wcout << L"Max:" << maxValue << L"Min:" << minValue << endl;

                    cCommand.Close();
                }
                cCommand.ReleaseCommand();
            }
        }
        CoTaskMemFree(pszSQL);
    }
}

int main()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        WindowsSearch(L"C:\\", L"test*.txt");
        CoUninitialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @G3D, is this answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. That doesn't quite address my problem. My function is recursive it broswse a hard drive. The travel time is too important when I throw it on c: (approximately 660,000 files). I memorize this description in a string array. If I remove this memorization it does not change the real time. Here's my function:
<<

bool Parcours_disque::EnumerateFolder(LPCWSTR lpcszFolder, DWORD nLevel)
{

```
// LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA fdd = __nullptr;
WIN32_FIND_DATAW fdd;
HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;


hFind = FindFirstFileW((lpcszFolder),(LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW) &fdd); // (LPCWSTR)

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind)
{
    return false;
}

do
{
    if (fdd.dwFileAttributes & (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
    {
        if (_T('.') != fdd.cFileName[0])

        {
            if (_T('$') != fdd.cFileName[0])
            {
             // Store in buffer
             .....
             EnumerateFolder(((CString)lpcszFolder).SpanExcluding(_T("*")) + (CString)fdd.cFileName + _T("\\*"), nLevel + 1);    // Here's the recursive call!
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
     // Store in buffer
     .....
    }

} while (FindNextFileW(hFind, (LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW) &fdd) != 0);

FindClose(hFind);

return true;
```

}

> > 

Microsoft does the same with CFileDialog object (MFC) and when you go through the disk it's immediate how does it do it? hidden functions?

Thank you

Comment: I am not familiar with `CFileDialog`, but I think it should load its sub-files only after you select a folder, instead of loading all the subfiles at once.